# Parse child JSON object in JSON array

Tags: apex, json, httprequest, parser

i am trying to parse a response which is a json object that has JSON array, what I need is to get value in the specific object from the array, inside "results" I'd like to get value from key "id" which is 5438.

[this question is similar to mine but it does not really solve my problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127467/how-to-deserialize-array-of-json-objects-to-an-apex-map)

my GET method response is

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "https://propertypro.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/5438.json",
            "id": 5438,
            "external_id": null,
            "via": {
                "channel": "any_channel",
                "source": {
                    "from": {
                        "service_info": {
                            "supports_channelback": true,
                            "supports_clickthrough": false,
                            "registered_integration_service_name": "WhatsApp",
                            "registered_integration_service_external_id": "wh"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

my full code

```
            // Set the GET request parameters
            String endpointGet = 'https://propertypro.zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json?'; // be sure this is configured in "Remote Site Settings"
            String resourceGetNoReplyWindow = 'query=type%3Aticket+tags%3Asend_whatsapp+status%3Cclosed';

            // Set the Methods
            String method_get = 'GET';

            // Set the credentials
            String username = 'some email'; 
            String password = 'Some password';

                // define transaction variables for 2 GET requests
                HttpRequest reqGetNrw = new HttpRequest();
                HttpResponse resGetNrw = new HttpResponse();
                Http hGetNrw = new Http();

                // Configure the 2 GET requests
                reqGetNrw.setEndpoint(endpointGet + resourceGetNoReplyWindow);
                reqGetNrw.setMethod(method_get);


                // Do the HTTP get request
                Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
                String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);

                reqGetNrw.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);            
                reqGetNrw.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                resGetNrw = hGetNrw.send(reqGetNrw);    

                                Map<String, Object> deserialized = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(resGetNrw.getBody());

                                List<Map<String, Object>> data = new List<Map<String, Object>>();

                                for(Object instance : (List<Object>)deserialized.get('results')){
                                    data.add((Map<String, Object>)instance);
                                }
                                    System.debug(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your in the right way!

Here, after getting instance as a Map, just retrieve the needed value:

```
Map<String, Object> deserialized = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(resGetNrw.getBody());

for (Object instance : (List<Object>) deserialized.get('results')) {
    Map<String, Object> data_i = (Map<String, Object>) instance;

    String id_i = (String) data_i.get('id');
    system.debug(id_i);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mariia, thanks for the quick response, your answer is what I'm looking for and I just need to convert the 'id' to string as its an integer type. thank you!

Comment: @AdnanZahry Or you just can leave it as Ier, for example, ```Integer id_i = (Integer) data_i.get('id');```

Comment: ah ok, one final thing, for instance when debugging, I get 2 list ```[77]|DEBUG|5617```  ```[77]|DEBUG|5606``` and I need to convert them into string and assign the value to new variable with comma separated, what I should do here?

Comment: Create List<String>, add values to yjis list instead of debugging ```.add((String) id-i)```, then make a ```String ans = String.join(yourListName, ',');```